# Highcharts Align pie charts to the Left

Tags: highcharts

**How can I align pie chart to the left?**

The pie chart shown on the demo is aligned centered.

Here is the demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/hp2t6zxr/3/

```
#container{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `series.center` to achieve that? API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.center